# How do Modalists explain the first person plural pronouns in John 14:23?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-john, modalism

John 14:23 says:

> Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, and **we will come** unto him, and **make our abode** (literally, we will make) with him.

Both of the emboldened verbs are in the 1st person plural form and so are properly rendered as we/our making it seem as though two distinct persons are involved.

How do Modalists explain the plural terms?